# Getting eloquvent error when accessing a DB entry

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im totally new to php/laravel.

I have defined a Model as follows(I have a table in DB,AlarmActions). in the **Doupdate** method, i like to return an entry based on the ID.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AlarmActions extends LobModel
{
    protected $table = 'AlarmActions';
    protected $primaryKey = 'AlarmActionId';

    public function scopeDoUpdate($alarmId)
    {
        return $alarmAction = \DB::table('AlarmActions')->where('AlarmActionId', $alarmId)->first();
    }

}
```

Im calling above class like;

```
$alarmAction = AlarmActions::doUpdate($id);
```

But Im getting;

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
t HandleExceptions->handleError(4096, 'Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder could not be converted to string', '/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php', 331, array('search' => '?', 'replace' => object(Builder), 'subject' => 'select top 1 * from [AlarmActions] where [AlarmActionId] = ?', 'position' => 59))
```

Looks like MY ID is not passed properly? What Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the first parameter in any `scope` method is `Query Builder` instance passed by `Laravel` and you should use other parameters after it,

so replace:

```
public function scopeDoUpdate($alarmId)
{
    return $alarmAction = \DB::table('AlarmActions')->where('AlarmActionId', $alarmId)->first();
}
```

by:

```
public function scopeDoUpdate($query, $alarmId)
{
    return $query->where('AlarmActionId', $alarmId)->first();
}
```

and you can still call it with:

```
$alarmAction = AlarmActions::doUpdate($id);
```